# How to count consecutive uppercase letters within a string?

Tags: c++

I am working on a project that tries to mirror http://uic.edu/apps/strong-password/. I can't seem to figure out how to count consecutive uppercase letters as well as lowercase or numbers. This is what I have so far

```
bool IsUpper(char c) {
    if ((c >= 65 && c <= 90))
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}

void consecUpper(string s) {
    int counter = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
        if (IsUpper(s[i > 1])) {
            counter++;
            
        }
    }
    gotoxy(73, 14);
    cout << counter;
}
```

What I need it to do 1. Read through the string(DONE) 2. If more than one Uppercase character occurs in an instance, begin counter. 3. stop when any other character is input. 4. Begin again if more than one uppercase is consecutively input.

What currently happens is 1: If more than the Uppercase character is detected. The counter begins counting anything input.
Or 2: after the second input if multiple Uppercase are input, the counter remains at 0.

Comment: 1) Can you fix the broken code formatting? 2) Can you make an example (or maybe a few) input string and corresponding output?

Comment: This post is lacking a [mre] that demonstrates an issue. SO is not a tutorial site. There are sufficient online tutorials and books available that can provide the information you need.

Comment: *"I honestly got my attempted solution off a Youtube video and barely understand it."* . Use that noggin and think about it on paper; not YouTube or Google search terms. If you wrote out a string on paper that had a smattering of mixed case and you wanted to find the longest sequence of upper-case characters, *write down* how you would do it. That is the amoeba in the tar pit; the beginning of life (or in your case, an *algorithm*). Iterate over that until you have confidence it can work; then craft code that matches it, then debug it, test it, etc.

Comment: There are a number of issues with your code, not the least of which is where you call `IsUpper(s[i] == prev)` , which is definitely not what you're trying to do. What is even the point of `prev`? It does nothing in the included code, other than the fact that the way you've used it breaks the function call.

Comment: @WhozCraig I appreciate the advice and will begin to do that.

Comment: @LayneBernardo I am going to start from scratch.

Comment: @KevinVillamizar We'll be here to help when you're done :)

Comment: While there may be a better way to get the job done, just about anything you need to do on a computer you can do the same way you'd do it with a piece of paper, a pencil, and someone calling out inputs. If nothing else, it gets you started.

Comment: @WhozCraig I updated and would like you guys to review.

Answer (score 0):

There are several issues with your code - I'm not trying to be rude but I would suggest that you become somewhat more familiar with the basics of C++ before attempting more complicated projects. Additionally, there is an issue with the algorithm you've come up with.

Let's take a look at how one would do this "on paper" first, as suggested by other commenters, and then we can take a look at the code issues.

By the way, I am assuming you want to count the TOTAL number of consecutive capital letters, where consecutive is defined as followed by at least one capital letter. This is how the reference app you've linked behaves; e.g., the string "AAAA" has three consecutive letters because the first "A" is not counted, and "AAAAbbbCC" would have four consecutive letters.

So let's get started.

Say we have a string, "ABAbbbCCddE" for example. We want to find that there are *three* consecutive capital letters in this string. We start at the left and have an "A", so we know that we've seen a capital letter. That means that we want to start counting if we continue seeing more capital letters. We see another capital, so now we've counted one. Then another, so we've counted two.

We then see some lowercase letters, which we ignore. Then, we see the first "C", and we know we should start counting again if we see another capital letter. We do, so we count up and have three. Now we skip past the "d"s and see an "E", but there's nothing after it so we're done. Now how would this look in code?

Well, first let me point out a few things with your existing code.

First, and most minor, is that there is no point in checking if a `boolean` is `true` and then returning `true` if it is - just return the `boolean`. Instead of this:

```
bool IsUpper(char c) {
    if ((c >= 65 && c <= 90))
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

Do this:

```
bool IsUpper(char c) {
    return (c >= 65 && c <= 90);
}
```

More importantly, you are not indexing your array correctly at all. I am very confused by what you are trying to accomplish here:

```
if (IsUpper( s[i > 1] ))
```

You should be calling `IsUpper()` with the `i`th array element of `s`, but instead you are comparing `i` to `1` and using *the result of that comparison* as the index into the array. The only reason this doesn't crash is because C++ will implicitly convert the `boolean` value into an integer for you, either zero or one.

To put it more simply, this is how this breaks down.

If `i` is less than or equal to one:

```
s[i > 1] -> s[false] -> s[0]
```

If `i` is greater than one:

```
s[i > 1] -> s[true] -> s[1]
```

This being said, I have gone ahead and written this algorithm up:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

inline bool IsUpper(char c) {
    return (c >= 65 && c <= 90);
}

void consecUpper(string s) {
    int counter = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i < s.length(); i++) {
        if ( IsUpper(s[i-1]) && IsUpper(s[i]) ) {
            counter++;
        }
    }
    cout << counter;
}

int main(){
    consecUpper("ABAbbbCCddE");
    return 0;
}
```

As you can see, in the loop I am starting at `i = 1`, because we are going to subtract one from `i` when we use it as an index into `s` in the first call to `IsUpper()`. We can't start at zero (and don't need to) because then we'll get an index of -1, which is invalid. It would be equally valid to start at 0 and compare `s[i]` to `s[i+1]` instead, but you would then need to stop the loop at `i < s.length() - 1`.

This algorithm simply compares each character side by side. If the previous character was uppercase and the current character is uppercase, then we add one to the counter. And that's it, we're done.

BONUS:

This method is inefficient because we need to call `IsUpper()` twice on every character of the string except for the first and last. `IsUpper()` isn't exactly the most computationally expensive function to compute, but in theory it could be if you needed a more complex evaluation. We could instead simply set a flag that indicates if the previous character was uppercase or not:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

inline bool IsUpper(char c) {
    return (c >= 65 && c <= 90);
}

void consecUpper(string s) {
    int counter = 0;
    bool lastCharUpper = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
        if (IsUpper(s[i])){
            if (lastCharUpper){
                counter++;
            }
            lastCharUpper = true;
        } else {
            lastCharUpper = false;
        }
    }
    cout << counter;
}

int main(){
    consecUpper("ABAbbbCCddE");
    return 0;
}
```

I suspect this might actually be slightly less efficient than simply calling `IsUpper()` twice per character, considering it is simply two comparisons and will likely be inlined. However, as previously stated, if calling a more complicated and expensive function you would probably want to use the flag approach. Note that we start the index at `i = 0` in this one, because we are no longer indexing with `i - 1`.

Comment: I want to thank you for your advice, your help, and the code you provided. I got 100% on my final project which in turn resulted in me passing the class. Many thanks and appreciation. Best of luck to you.